# Simple Query MariaDB getting very slow

Tags: mysql, indexing, mariadb

I have this simple query

```
SELECT  item_code, stock_value, name, warehouse
    FROM  `tabStock Ledger Entry` sle
    WHERE  posting_date <= '2020-08-01'
      AND  warehouse = 'bom'
    ORDER BY  timestamp(posting_date, posting_time) DESC,
              Creation DESC
```

It takes almost 3 secs for 1000 records..without Order By clause, it only takes less than 1 sec to query whole table. the table itself has 1M+ records currently.

`show processlist` always stuck on State Creating Sort Index.

Explain query showed:

```
+------+-------------+-------+------+------------------------------+-----------+---------+-------+--------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                | key       | key_len | ref   | rows   | Extra                                              |
+------+-------------+-------+------+------------------------------+-----------+---------+-------+--------+----------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | sle   | ref  | posting_sort_index,warehouse | warehouse | 563     | const | 127740 | Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort |
+------+-------------+-------+------+------------------------------+-----------+---------+-------+--------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

table indexes as follows:

```
   +-----------------------+------------+-------------------------------+--------------+--------------+--
| Table                 | Non_unique | Key_name                      | Seq_in_index | Column_name  | C
+-----------------------+------------+-------------------------------+--------------+--------------+--
| tabStock Ledger Entry |          0 | PRIMARY                       |            1 | name         | A
| tabStock Ledger Entry |          1 | item_code                     |            1 | item_code    | A
| tabStock Ledger Entry |          1 | parent                        |            1 | parent       | A
| tabStock Ledger Entry |          1 | posting_sort_index            |            1 | posting_date | A
| tabStock Ledger Entry |          1 | posting_sort_index            |            2 | posting_time | A
| tabStock Ledger Entry |          1 | posting_sort_index            |            3 | name         | A
| tabStock Ledger Entry |          1 | voucher_no_voucher_type_index |            1 | voucher_no   | A
| tabStock Ledger Entry |          1 | voucher_no_voucher_type_index |            2 | voucher_type | A
| tabStock Ledger Entry |          1 | warehouse                     |            1 | warehouse    | A
| tabStock Ledger Entry |          1 | warehouse                     |            2 | posting_date | A
+-----------------------+------------+-------------------------------+--------------+--------------+--
```

Added index for (posting_date,warehouse) or (warehouse, posting_date) but it doesn't help..the query seems to always using file sort

`innodb_buffer_pool_size` is 2G..out of 4G RAM. I think its enough..its not a mega giant database

`SHow Create table` as follows:

```
+-----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
| Table                 | Create Table
+-----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
| tabStock Ledger Entry | CREATE TABLE `tabStock Ledger Entry` (
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `creation` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_by` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `owner` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `docstatus` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `parent` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `parentfield` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `parenttype` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `idx` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `actual_qty` decimal(18,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.000000,
  `warehouse` varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `qty_after_transaction` decimal(18,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.000000,
  `fiscal_year` varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `company` varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `serial_no` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `incoming_rate` decimal(18,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.000000,
  `stock_queue` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_code` varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `voucher_detail_no` varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `project` varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `stock_value_difference` decimal(18,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.000000,
  `stock_uom` varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `voucher_type` varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `batch_no` varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `valuation_rate` decimal(18,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.000000,
  `posting_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `voucher_no` varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `stock_value` decimal(18,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.000000,
  `is_cancelled` varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `posting_time` time(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `outgoing_rate` decimal(18,6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.000000,
  `_comments` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `_liked_by` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `_assign` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `_user_tags` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `to_rename` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`),
  KEY `item_code` (`item_code`),
  KEY `parent` (`parent`),
  KEY `posting_sort_index` (`posting_date`,`posting_time`,`name`),
  KEY `voucher_no_voucher_type_index` (`voucher_no`,`voucher_type`),
  KEY `warehouse` (`warehouse`,`posting_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED
+-----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
```

**MORE**

I removed timestamp function and order by posting_date only..run the query from mariadb console..finally it only took < 2 sec to load over 200.000 resulted rows.

But **mariadb-slow.log** showed me differently if I ran the same query from web application..it took > 4sec for same result. **What might cause this?**

```
# User@Host: _5839b22099d630d5[_5839b22099d630d5] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]
# Thread_id: 685  Schema: _5839b22099d630d5  QC_hit: No
# Query_time: 4.101652  Lock_time: 0.000055  Rows_sent: 226657  Rows_examined: 226657
# Rows_affected: 0
SET timestamp=1596384652;
SELECT item_code, stock_value, name, warehouse
                FROM `tabStock Ledger Entry` sle
                WHERE posting_date <= '2020-08-02'  AND warehouse = 'bom'
                ORDER BY posting_date DESC;
```

EXPLAIN In JSON

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "table": {
      "table_name": "sle",
      "access_type": "range",
      "possible_keys": [
        "warehouse",
        "posting_date",
        "posting_sort_index",
        "warehouse_2"
      ],
      "key": "warehouse_2",
      "key_length": "567",
      "used_key_parts": ["warehouse", "posting_date"],
      "rows": 126605,
      "filtered": 100,
      "attached_condition": "sle.warehouse <=> 'bom' and sle.posting_date <= '2020-08-02' and sle.warehouse = 'bom'"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you check what happens if you only order by one of the two statements. Perhaps the creation of the timestamp takes so long. Why don’t you just order by date, time instead of passing them to timestamp function?

Comment: Which version of MariaDB?

Comment: 10.2.31-MariaDB-1:10.2.31+m

Comment: It takes 4 seconds to shovel 226657 rows out the door.  What will the client do with that much stuff?  Rows_examined is an important factor in the total time taken.

Answer (score 0):

Add this composite index:

```
INDEX(warehouse, posting_date)
```

(And, if you currently have `INDEX(warehouse)`, drop it.)

For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the complete `EXPLAIN` in text (not image).

More on index creation:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Timings:

- There could have been caching differences.  When running timings, run the query twice.  The first may do I/O that the second does not need to do.
- When it used the index, it needed to reach over into the data's BTree 1000 times.  These random fetches may have been disk hits.
- Other...  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`; is the table InnoDB; how much RAM do you have; how big (in GB) is the table?

**More**

```
timestamp(posting_date, posting_time) DESC, Creation DESC
```

in not "sargable".  I suspect this gives you the same results more efficiently:

```
posting_date DESC, posting_time DESC, Creation DESC
```

In general, it is clumsy to split a datetime into two columns, and it is much easier to pull parts out of a `DATETIME` (or `TIMESTAMP`) when needed.  I recommend combining `posting_date` and `posting_time` into a single `DATETIME(6)`.

After that, I recommend adding

```
INDEX(warehouse, posting_datetime)
```

Caution:  `posting_date <= '2020-08-01'` includes all of Aug 1.  posting_datetime <= '2020-08-01' includes only `microsecond of Aug 1.  If you meant to exclude all of Aug 1, then change`<=`to`<`; then both variants work 'correctly'.

The optimizer *may* prefer this over the previous index I recommended.

> 2G..out of 4G RAM

That's right; make sure you are not swapping.

> 1000 records

What do you do with 1000 records?  That's a lot to present to a web user.

> no improvement
> only 0.1 sec to query the whole table

These are puzzling.  Please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` -- this should provide some more info.

**More-take 2**

> Rows_sent: 226657  Rows_examined: 226657

Those two numbers are equal, so there is little or no wasted effort on the part of the query.  Every row that it fetched, it used.

There are some things still...

- I think it is avoiding the sort, but that EXPLAIN fails to have that detail.  Could you run `ANALYZE FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` and try with the "optimizer trace" (if available in your version).
- The size of the table relative to the buffer_pool_size is still to be investigated.  With a 2G buffer_pool and a table that might be about that size, I worry that the query is I/O bound.

To chase this last item, there are two possibilities.  Each will aim to help *this one* query without necessarily helping any others.  Is this query somehow "more important"?

- A covering index:  `INDEX(warehouse, posting_date, item_code, stock_value, name)`.  (If you try this, please use `EXPLAIN` to confirm that this index is being used.)
- Change the `PRIMARY KEY` and my index to:

  ```
    PRIMARY KEY(warehouse, posting_date, item_code, stock_value, name),
    UNIQUE(name)
  ```

The current PK (name) is still indexed, and its uniqueness confirms that my PK will still be unique.  But it will also "cluster" the data such that the query will not be jumping around the table.

Comment: hi thx for answer.. i have edited my question with detailed Explain result, complete table indexes and innodb_buffer setting. Added index per your suggestion (warehouse, posting_date) but no improvement.. if I remove Order By clause then it takes only 0.1 sec to query whole table(1M+ records)..so how to speed up Order By clause index? Thx again

Comment: @JonathanFLie - "Rows_sent: 226657" will take seconds.  I'll look at things to see if we can speed it up _some_.  What will you do with all those rows?

Comment: it's a web erp system to show stock mutation ledger report..what i;m confusing about is why the query seems to run faster via mariadb console < 2sec..but from web application mariadb-slow.log showed differently which is >4sec.. do you have idea ?

Comment: Were the two timings for the _same_ running of the query?  (Check the timestamps.)  I ask this because I want to know which anomaly you are reporting -- (1) different times for the _same_ query versus (2) the same SQL runs slower or faster when run again or (3) the client causes the different timing.

Comment: the same query ran in same timing..if I ran the query directly from mariadb console it seems faster.

Comment: Hi Rick, back again here.. The issue is date range clause and order by timestamp column. If I removed order by clause it took me 2-3 sec to compete query for over 1M+ records. Can order by indexed or any other option to speed up order by clause, date range clause. Do you have suggestions?

Comment: @JonathanFLie - If you have combined the two posting columns into `posting_datetime` and do `ORDER BY posting_datetime DESC` (no `creation`) and have `INDEX(warehouse, posting_datetime)`, then it might be efficient.

Comment: I tried using just order by posting_date desc, result is very slow for almost 30 seconds. as far as I remove order by date clause, the query is fast. Any ideas?

Comment: @JonathanFLie - Did `Rows_examined` increase?  Was some other query busy with that table?

Comment: Rows_sent: 1080072  Rows_examined: 2160144. Slow query log stated that it used Filesort. How to make it using index?

Comment: Please show us the current `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, `SELECT`, and `EXPLAIN`.